# SemephoreSlim.AwaitAsync() does not continue when released

Tags: c#, async-await, semaphore

I have the following code which uses a semaphore to allow a maximum concurrency;

```
 _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, _settings.MaximumConcurrentRequests);
```

....

```
//Release based on maximum. Without doing this, the semaphore is the maximum when starting and will therefore not process anything further 
_semaphore.Release(_settings.MaximumConcurrentRequests);
```

....

```
 try
            {
                if (_semaphore.CurrentCount == 0)
                    _logger.LogDebug("Semaphore limit reached for Case {caseId}", caseId);

                //If we have reached maximum concurrency, there will be a delay here until that Task has completed.
                await _semaphore.WaitAsync(token);

                _logger.LogInformation("Processing Case: {caseId}", caseId);

                await _httpService.ProcessCase(caseId, token);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("{ex}", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Semaphore released for Case {caseId}", caseId);
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
```

The current settings allow 10 cases to be processed at any 1 time and I have 45 available within my test environment. The first 10 are completed, none of the subsequent cases are processed and I end up having to cancel them. Excerpt from logs;

```
2021-12-10 09:57:34.432 +00:00 [DBG] Adding case: "4e262c8e-9e32-461e-8b56-d2f679041514" to Tasks array
2021-12-10 09:57:34.432 +00:00 [DBG] Adding case: "290c5a7c-5b2f-4e63-8a78-0156dd705161" to Tasks array
2021-12-10 09:57:34.432 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case (HTTP): "40a15e58-e7b3-4143-8a63-06a80966a86f"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.432 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case (HTTP): "7f96ed9b-5c8c-42b3-9f05-20bf12f7a004"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.432 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case (HTTP): "b8a59367-abb2-4063-90dc-817707155c77"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.432 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case (HTTP): "9f285d28-9be3-460f-a5bc-6c806a436205"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.666 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case: "e3e1d60c-cf86-405a-8c12-9bc7903eaecb"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore limit reached for Case "978b7f55-0901-4187-9a2f-22ed234fcd12"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case (HTTP): "e3e1d60c-cf86-405a-8c12-9bc7903eaecb"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore limit reached for Case "804646f8-6421-4029-99d1-948952487c41"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore limit reached for Case "abdbe15b-bd11-42c1-9b1c-64544078ed45"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore limit reached for Case "3cbef0c2-17dc-420c-b30b-a7719325baf7"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore limit reached for Case "8566aa4a-c7e3-4caf-9a34-ff20cd97c4a0"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore limit reached for Case "acc3d22f-a53e-4869-a17b-be9f2917e5c1"
2021-12-10 09:57:34.682 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore limit reached for Case "32ad7155-f519-49c0-8cd7-a620dd586175"
.....
2021-12-10 09:57:35.477 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"7f96ed9b-5c8c-42b3-9f05-20bf12f7a004"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.477 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"b8a59367-abb2-4063-90dc-817707155c77"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.477 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"e3e1d60c-cf86-405a-8c12-9bc7903eaecb"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.477 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"40a15e58-e7b3-4143-8a63-06a80966a86f"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.493 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "40a15e58-e7b3-4143-8a63-06a80966a86f"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.493 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "e3e1d60c-cf86-405a-8c12-9bc7903eaecb"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.493 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "b8a59367-abb2-4063-90dc-817707155c77"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.493 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "7f96ed9b-5c8c-42b3-9f05-20bf12f7a004"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.493 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"9f285d28-9be3-460f-a5bc-6c806a436205"
2021-12-10 09:57:35.493 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "9f285d28-9be3-460f-a5bc-6c806a436205"
```

....

Then nothing until I cancel.

```
2021-12-10 10:12:26.537 +00:00 [ERR] System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The code itself is contained within a single API. Essentially, the API exposes 2 methods ProcessBatch and ProcessCase and ProcessBatch will call ProcessCase over another http channel (this is load balanced). Interestingly, if the call to ProcessBatch is done from my local machine with the call to ProcessCase on the dev server, it works fine.

EDIT updated code to add additional debug information;

```
var result = _semaphore.Release();
_logger.LogDebug("Semaphore released for Case {caseId}, semaphore result {result}", caseId, result);


2021-12-10 12:01:34.706 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"abdbe15b-bd11-42c1-9b1c-64544078ed45"
2021-12-10 12:01:34.706 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"804646f8-6421-4029-99d1-948952487c41"
2021-12-10 12:01:34.706 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"3cbef0c2-17dc-420c-b30b-a7719325baf7"
2021-12-10 12:01:34.722 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "abdbe15b-bd11-42c1-9b1c-64544078ed45", semaphore result 0
2021-12-10 12:01:34.722 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "804646f8-6421-4029-99d1-948952487c41", semaphore result 2
2021-12-10 12:01:34.722 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "3cbef0c2-17dc-420c-b30b-a7719325baf7", semaphore result 1
2021-12-10 12:01:34.722 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"978b7f55-0901-4187-9a2f-22ed234fcd12"
2021-12-10 12:01:34.722 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "978b7f55-0901-4187-9a2f-22ed234fcd12", semaphore result 3
2021-12-10 12:01:34.722 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"04e1e60a-2ae9-4455-b391-f0b95a38544b"
2021-12-10 12:01:34.722 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "04e1e60a-2ae9-4455-b391-f0b95a38544b", semaphore result 4
```

This is the log file for calling ProcessBatch locally with then calls ProcessCase remotely, but identical code;

```
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "f043a848-9abf-4b25-903c-2116169005b6", semaphore result 0
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "1dcc23f6-411f-4f38-89a3-0613d8e2058d", semaphore result 0
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "aabcbd73-6434-4097-99f8-f51b17b819d9", semaphore result 0
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "acc3d22f-a53e-4869-a17b-be9f2917e5c1", semaphore result 0
2021-12-10 12:05:47.935 +00:00 [INF] Response : "OK" received for Case:"ff784399-c213-402d-b031-921a0ffd1367"
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [DBG] Semaphore released for Case "ff784399-c213-402d-b031-921a0ffd1367", semaphore result 0
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case: "f35d4e1a-70f1-4b7a-af0b-06f553736726"
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case: "32ad7155-f519-49c0-8cd7-a620dd586175"
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case: "8566aa4a-c7e3-4caf-9a34-ff20cd97c4a0"
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case (HTTP): "8566aa4a-c7e3-4caf-9a34-ff20cd97c4a0"
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case: "293239fd-6888-413d-b67a-44f5f1eaf487"
2021-12-10 12:05:47.936 +00:00 [INF] Processing Case: "416e5527-894f-42ac-a6f6-56ef83c322e2"
```

It looks to me that as soon as the semaphore is released, one of the other Tasks that continues so this is only a problem with remote to remote but I fail to see why that would matter here.

Comment: Where is `Processing Case (HTTP):` coming from? There is only 1 row that matches your logging code: `Processing Case:`.

Comment: I assume you're releasing the initial number of semaphores before this all starts? I ask because you pass 0 as the initial count into the semaphore, which means it starts out as fully consumed, as in no thread will complete the wait for it.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay That comes from the implementation of ProcessCase, the same as the "received response X for case Y"

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, updated with that line.

Comment: When you call `_semaphore.Release();` does it return a non null positive value?

Comment: @LaurentGabiot Updated code and re-ran, results above. Looks okay to me.

Comment: Thanks, yes, your new log shows that the semaphore gets released...

Comment: Is there any chance of disposal of the class that holds the semaphore (or the semaphore itself) before all Tasks are performed?

Comment: They are all added  with a scoped context and we are not explicitly disposing of anything. I would also add that when we cancel the exception is thrown by the semaphore, so that at least is certainly present and correct.